# Converting GDAL dataset into numpy array

Tags: python, gdal, numpy

I am trying to do data augmentation on sentinel 2. Everything else is working and the only problem I have is the output I am getting is only one band when the input image has 10 bands. I also tried with **rasterio** but the results are still only one band.

Why am I only getting one band as output?

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
# import io
from PIL import Image
from osgeo import gdal
import cv2
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=180,
        width_shift_range=0,
        height_shift_range=0,
        shear_range=0,
        zoom_range=0.5,
        
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip = True,
        fill_mode='nearest')    #Also try nearest, constant, reflect, wrap


a = 1
while True:
    ds = gdal.Open("E:\\opencv\\12.tif")
    myarray = np.array(ds.ReadAsArray())
       ""Rasterio code"" 
    #fp = r'E:\\opencv\\12.tif'
    #img = rasterio.open(fp)
    #img = img.read()
    """"""
    x = img_to_array(myarray)
    x = x.reshape(x.shape + (1, ))  
    i = 1
    for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=16,  
        save_to_dir='E:\\opencv\\', 
        save_prefix= a, 
        save_format='tif'):
        i += 1
        if i > 1:
            break 
    a += 1
    if a > 3:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify which band in the dataset you want to read as an array. I would also open your dataset outside of the while loop as this will prevent corruption

```
a = 1
ds = gdal.Open("E:\\opencv\\12.tif")

while True:
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(a)
    myarray = band.ReadAsArray()
    x = img_to_array(myarray)
    x = x.reshape(x.shape + (1, ))  
    i = 1
    for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=16,  
        save_to_dir='E:\\opencv\\', 
        save_prefix= a, 
        save_format='tif'):
        i += 1
        if i > 1:
            break 
    a += 1
    if a > 12: #ensures you get all 12 bands
        break
del ds
```